# Problems with shell-script while!

Tags: linux, shell

First of all, I'm a beginner on shell-script. This code I've done is not working.

I want to repeat a code for 30 seconds but it doesn't work. It just keep doing my logic indefinitely.

```
DIFF=0

while [ $DIFF < 30 ]; do

    START=$(date +%s)

######## My logic #########

    DIFF=$(( $END - $START ))
    echo $DIFF
    cd ..
    sleep 5s

done
```

I think it's because I'm not doing the while clause properly?

Comment: My 2nd edit is a working 1-line version of the solution to this; it should do pretty much what you want.

Comment: The 'cd ..' part is odd; it will work (the root directory is its own parent directory, so when you've reached the top - root - another 'cd ..' does nothing) but is probably not what you had in mind.

Comment: You want to capture the start time before the loop, and the current end time (only) within the loop.  The 's' on the end of the argument to sleep is unnecessary; it probably won't cause errors anywhere, but only seconds are POSIX standard (anything else is an extension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you definitely need to provide some values for `$START` and `$END`. They won't set themselves!

You may want to do something like

```
START = `date +%s`
```

to set it to a time in seconds. Of course `END` will need to be set inside your loop to get it updated.

EDIT: `cd ..` is hopefully not really what you plan to run inside the loop. Within a few milliseconds your current directory will be the root directory, with little else accomplished. It would be cheaper to do a single `cd /` .

---

EDIT 2: This shouldn't be such a hard problem. For this edit, I've built and tested a one-line solution:

```
START=$(date +%s); DIFF=0; while [ $DIFF -lt 30 ]; do echo $DIFF; DIFF=$(($(date +%s)-$START)); done
```

That will correctly update its variables and display them... and it ends after 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks....But it was already done... sorry I made a mistake when I postate it...

As you can notice I do an "echo $DIFF" so it shows me the DIFF value it's really going okay with the $DIFF value but the computer stays on the loop when DIFF is 200 ... 300 and so on.

Comment: Why did you remove the OP's beautiful `$()` and replace it with ugly `\`\``? And spaces around the equal sign won't work, by the way.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Because I'm no shell script expert and wasn't aware of the subtleties - thanks for the info! In my defense, the OP had no beautiful `$()` when I wrote my post; he edited that in later, I think.

Answer (score 2):

```
((end = $(date +%s) + 30))
while (( $(date +%s) < end ))
do
    something
done
```

Or, using the builtin variable `$SECONDS` in Bash:

```
((end = SECONDS + 30))
while (( SECONDS < end ))
do
    something
done
```

Comment: Ooh, there's a `$SECONDS` ? Spiffy, that's a nice thing to know. +1.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using bash.

Try something like this perhaps:

```
START=...
while (($DIFF<30)); do
   #   ....
   DIFF=$((END-START))
done
```

(See [Bash arithmetic evaluation](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-10.html) and [The Double-Parentheses Construct](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html).)

Comment: Sorry, I had misread an important point of course. As Carl Smotricz mentioned in his answer, don't reset START within the loop.

Comment: "# assigment ($ only outside)" or not at all: `(( DIFF = END - START ))` and `(( DIFF < 30 ))` Note that the double-parentheses permits spacing around operators/operands.

Comment: Hum... not by best answer, sorry. You're right. I've edited to remove my incorrect comments. Hopefully, the pointers might be useful to the original poster at least.

Answer (score 1):

use an infinite loop. an example pseudocode

```
DIFF=0
while true
do
  START=$(date +%s)
  END=.... #define your end
  DIFF=$((END-START))
  if [ "$DIFF" -gt 30 ] ;then
    break
  fi
  .....
done
```